# MVC 5.1 - Adding Html attributes in EditorFor with customized Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I can add htmlAttributes like following and its rendered in Html

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.LastName, New With {Key .htmlAttributes = New With {Key .ng_model = "model.LastName"}})
```

But when I added a custom editor template for Date Data type in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.vbhtml` as follows

```
@Code
    Dim value = ""
    If Not Model Is Nothing Then
        value = String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    End If
    @Html.TextBox("", value, New With {Key .class = "datefield", Key .type = "text"})
End Code
```

and I use the EditorFor with htmlAttributes then the HtmlAttributes are not rendering?

Comment: Maybe a good idea to post what is rendered instead of telling that it is not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of code I am using for a custom DateTime editor template.  I was able to access the htmlattributes being passed into editorfor.  Hope this helps.

```
@model DateTime

@{
    object htmlAttributes = null;
    if (ViewContext.ViewData.Keys.Contains("htmlAttributes"))
    {
        htmlAttributes = ViewContext.ViewData["htmlAttributes"];
    }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, htmlAttributes)
```